# Powershell return variable from within a Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I'm developing a powershell script (and kind of new to it) to go to a couple of servers and extract the RDP logons, so we can check if a certain policy is being followed.
So I've search a bit and now I got the script output exatcly as I want. But now I want to send the result over email.
But I have a problem, because the variable which is output to console (with the info I need) is inside a Invoke-Command, so I cannot use it after outside the Invoke-Command to send the email.
This is my code:

```
$ServersToCheck = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Servers-RDP2.txt"
foreach ($server in $ServersToCheck) {

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue {
        $username = "user"
        $FilterPath = "<QueryList><Query Id='0'><Select Path='Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational'>*[System[(EventID=1149) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 604800000]]] and *[UserData[EventXML[@xmlns='Event_NS'][Param1='{0}']]]</Select></Query></QueryList>" -f $username
        $RDPAuths = Get-WinEvent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational' -FilterXPath $FilterPath
        [xml[]]$xml = $RDPAuths | Foreach { $_.ToXml() }
        $EventData = Foreach ($event in $xml.Event) {
            New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                TimeCreated = (Get-Date ($event.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime) -Format 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss')
                User        = $event.UserData.EventXML.Param1
                Domain      = $event.UserData.EventXML.Param2
                Client      = $event.UserData.EventXML.Param3
                Server      = hostname
            }
        } 
        $EventData | FT
    }
}
```

So, I need to use $EventData outside the Invoke-Command so I can add the results of all servers and then send it over by email.
How can I use that variable outside the Invoke-Command?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `| FT`, then collect the output from the whole loop with `$AllEventData = foreach($server ...){ ...}`

Comment: Note that you can run in parallel with `invoke-command $serverstocheck`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was able to get the result with this tip.